# Vimeo video ajax upload

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload a video to Vimeo account via ajax request. The reason I'm doing it is necessity to upload multiply videos simultaneously. In short: I'm generating multiply video upload forms on php backend, fetching action URLs from them and making simultaneous ajax requests on frontend like this

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'https://1512435583.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=...',
       method: 'post',
       data: formDataObject,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
})
```

The problem is that Vimeo post video uploading is implemented with 2 redirects instead of 1, that I set via `redirect_url`. So all my ajax requests are redirected to `https://vimeo.com/upload/api?video_file_id=...` but browser throws the following error
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://1512435583.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=1...' from origin 'http://localhost.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
Can anybody advise is it possible to upload multiply videos to Vimeo simultaneously?

Comment: Yes of course it's possible but you need to create a new upload ticket for each of those videos. What do you mean by form? Why redirect_url? There shouldn't be any. Did you add localhost to your Vimeo's App website list (on vimeo platform)?

Comment: Hi @kemicofa, sorry for a really huge delay :)
I still didn't manage to implement ajax upload of multiply videos.

Comment: Please let me split your questions:
1. Sure I'm creating new upload ticket for each video.
2 . "By form" means, that I choose this upload method. Vimeo has 3 upload approaches https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos.
3. When using form upload, while creating new video ticket, redirect_url can be provided (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#form-based-approach-step-1). Even if it's not provided, there will be a default value.
4. This doesn't fit for me, because I need the ability to upload videos for any user of a site.

Thanks.

Comment: is there any solution to vimeo  cors ?